# Preventing "Email not found" error from Firebase when calling Send Password Reset Email method

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication and the Javascript client library for my web app to allow users to log in and out. I've implemented a "Forgot Password" form to allow a user to reset their password. When this form submits, it calls the `sendPasswordResetEmail` method. This all works fine, the password is successfully reset.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.email)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Success");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("Shhhhh");
      });
  };
```

However, if I enter an email that hasn't signed up yet, I get a console error that logs the 400 response from Firebase. The network tab in the dev-tools basically spells out that the email wasn't found. It's my understanding that surfacing this information to the user is generally considered poor security practice(please correct me if I'm wrong). Catching the error (as I've attempted to do above) does not prevent the logging of this information. I've also run the code in a production environment and gotten the same result.

The leads me to thinking that I should check for the email first before calling the `sendPasswordResetEmail` method. However, in searching SO for similar issues, there doesn't seem to be agreement on the best way to check for a users existence outside of the sign-up flow. You can check if a user exists using the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users), but this requires a privileged environment (like a server).

So I guess my main question is two-fold: Can/Should I suppress the "Email Not Found" error message from the firebase `sendPasswordResetEmail` method? If yes, how? If no, what is the best way of determining if an email address has already been used to sign in to my firebase app?

Comment: Is your catch not catching the error?

Comment: It does actually, but a network request error is logged to the console anyway, and that one I can't catch.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to supress the console output, however, you could always make an API that checks for the users existence and depending on what that API returns you could send/not send the reset email. 
Also, this might be helpful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to @Alchemist Shahed who pointed me to the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail) method, which returns an array of signin methods for a given email. If the array is empty, then they have not signed in yet. I modified my above code to look like the following:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.state.email)
    .then(result => {
      if (result.length > 0) {
        firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.email).catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error Sending Email", error);
        });
      }
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error Reaching Firebase: ", error);
    });
  };
```

As an aside, the Admin SDK apparently doesn't have a `sendPasswordResetEmail` method. However, if your preference is to call the `sendPasswordResetEmail` from an API, you can use both the Javascript SDK and Node.js SDK together on a server [as described in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51320977/5775341)