# Firebase prevent leaking existence of email account

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

It is generally considered to be bad practice to leak whether an
email is registered with your website or not. However, I am struggling to find a way to stop Firebase calls from leaking this information. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826392/preventing-email-not-found-error-from-firebase-when-calling-send-password-rese), part of the problem is solved - Firebase would respond with a 400 status and leak an error in the case that the email was not registered. The solution given was to test whether the email is registered before making the reset call. This still leaks easy to find information - if you take a look at the Network log. Below is a an example:

**Account Exist**:
[Account Exists Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oQfg.png)

**Account Does NOT Exist**
[Account Does Not Exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txVQX.png)

As you can see, extra calls are made in the case that the email does exist.

Below is a snippet showing implementation details:

```
//need to handle attempting to reset password
try {
    const signInOptions = await firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(data.email);
    if(signInOptions.length > 0)
        await firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(data.email);
    setStatementMessage('Email sent');
} catch(e) {
    if(e === 'auth/user-not-found') {
        setStatementMessage('Email sent'); 
    }
    console.log(e);
}
```

How can I reset a user's password using Firebase Auth without leaking whether there exists an account?

Comment: If somebody could see the network log, then they would be able to see everything that the user does, including the password they use to log in, so there's no way to design this such that information doesn't exist in the network log. You can, however, use HTTPS to prevent others from being able to sniff a user's traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the status codes of the wire protocol make a difference here: the whole purpose for the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method is to find out whether a specific email address is in use in the Firebase project.

If you use Firebase Authentication, anyone can take the configuration data for your project, and call this API with specific values to test if those are registered.

This behavior is inherent to Firebase Authentication (and most other serverless auth systems that I know of), and cannot be disabled or circumvented.

Comment: Frank, thanks for the response. I now see that this is true - anyone can query the API with your public apiKey. There doesn't seem to be a way to hide which emails hold accounts.

Comment: thank you add i am really invest so much time on this task

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to obfuscate the information being leaked (since you can not prevent it - see Frank's answer for details), you can implement this in your backend with a direct call as such:

```
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getOobConfirmationCode?key=[public apiKey]', 
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: '{"requestType":"PASSWORD_RESET","email": "' + request.body.email + '"}',
    });
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52711058/6879382)