# Flutter firebase reset password without log-in

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to reset firebase user password without logged-in. I am implementing forget-password screen where the user enter their email address and will send OTP to user email address, OTP is stored in firebase database collection. once OTP is verified then they can reset their password from flutter app itself.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

**Firebase SDKs** correlated with the client-side only permit users to send password reset to the signed-in user because other calls can be an abusive factor. **Unfortunately**, there is no way to send password reset information to a user based on their email address alone.

If you want to implement this feature, you must do it by yourself. You can learn more at this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Moreover, you can check out this article to implement this functionality related to the backend: [Send Firebase Reset Password Email After Account Created On Server/Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979478/send-firebase-reset-password-email-after-account-created-on-server-admin)

Comment: Thanks for the response. For flutter managing user information only if the user is already authenticated. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users Already implemented password reset by using firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(userEmail); I don't know whether it is possible to reset the user password with his email alone.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to send password reset information to a user based on their email address alone. (Firebase)